# Como formatar php mail?

Tags: php, email

Não estou conseguindo inserir formatação no código.
Sempre que faço o envio, recebo o e-mail as tag de formatação como `<html>` `<body>`, `<strong>`, `<b>`, `<p>`, etc...

Segue o código com a formatação html que não funciona.

```
    $to = $your_email;
    $subject="Pedido $numeroPedido de $name";
    $from = $your_email;
    $ip = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '';

    $html ="
    <p><b>$name</b> enviou um arquivo mensagem:</p>
    <p><b>Número do Pedido:</b> $numeroPedido</p>   
    <p><b>Endereço:</b> $endereco</p>
    <p><b>Endereço:</b> $estado</p>     
    <p><b>Cidade:</b> $cidade</p>
    <p><b>Telefone:</b> $telefone
    <p><b>Celular:</b> $celular</p>                         
    <p><b>Email:</b> $visitor_email</p>
    <p><b>Informações Adicionais:</b></p>
    <p>$user_message</p>
    <p><b>IP:</b> $ip</p>
    ";  

    $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $html, $headers)) {
```

Desde já agradeço =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adicione um cabeçalho, definido qual vai ser o tipo do email, text/plain(padrão) ou text/html. Existem outra opções mais práticas para isso, como o [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) ou [swiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

```
$headers = "From: $from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Perfeito, esqueci deste detalhe =)

Obrigado o/